# Unable to select radio choices of form

Tags: html, django, forms

I have an HTML with 2 forms. I want to be able to select one from the first two and one from the next three radio buttons. How to I achieve this? Given below is the html snippet:

```
<form method="POST" action="/profiles/adminKaLogin/">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline1" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample" value="1">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">Vendor 1</label>
        </div>

        <!-- Default inline 2-->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline2" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample" value="2">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">Vendor 2</label>
        </div>

    <h3> Select time period</h3>

        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline1" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample1" value="1m">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline1">1 Month</label>
        </div>  
        <!-- Default inline 2-->
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline2" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample1" value="2m">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">2 Months</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline">
            <input type="radio" class="custom-control-input" id="defaultInline2" name="inlineDefaultRadiosExample1" value="6m">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="defaultInline2">6 Months</label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="form1">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Note that these buttons have to be in groups of 2 and 3, because I have different uses for them in the backend. Thanks.

Comment: none of your input elements have values. When you say you `"want to be able to select one from the first two ... etc"` - what is the problem? Are you meaning specifically in django?

Comment: Ah sorry. Have updated the post with values. So what i am trying to do is to get user to select vendor(first two options) and the time period(last 3 options), based on which I will do retrievals. The problem that I am facing is that I am not able to select any of the three last buttons.

Comment: `" I am not able to select any of the three last buttons"` ?? The form works fine and I can click(select) any radio button so I am unclear as to the reason why you cannot select one of the last 3 radio buttons - pleas, can you clarify?

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working for me. I am able to select between the first two options(vendor 1 and vendor 2) only, unable to choose from the next 3 buttons.

Comment: It's working fine in the online editors where bootstrap isn't involved, maybe it is  something about classes or id's that I am unable to catch.

Comment: perhaps use the developer tools to `"inspect"` the html at that point to see if there is some css causing these radio buttons to be unclickable ( z-index perhaps with div element on top somehow? )

Comment: I got it. The id's of the last three options were same as the other two. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you gave the same ids of the 1st and 2nd labels and input to the 3/4 and 5th labels and inputs ids

Try to give unique matching for every "id" and "for"

Hope I could help

With that it's working on my environment with bootstrap.